# How can I tell if the current thread was created as an NSThread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, macos, cocoa, pthreads

I get C++ callbacks from a purchased media-streaming SDK Library, that creates several threads internally.

Specifically, I receive callbacks when the library wants to log a message. Sometimes I'm called in the context of some NSThread, where there is an Autorelease pool, but sometimes I'm called from other threads, that do not have autorelease pool. Some of the calling threads are realtime threads (audio grabbing etc.) so performance is important.

How can I differentiate between situations where I'm called within an NSThread (Application's main thread, or other NSThreads) and internal "C++ only" threads created by the SDK library?

Nothing in Apple's documentation tells me what happens when I use

[NSThread currentThread]

when I'm in a context of another kind of thread, and what happens when I'm calling pthreadSelf() or similar API, on an NSThread.

In addition, I'd like to hear ideas about attaching autorelease pools to those internal threads, if possible, and about draining them from time to time.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're in a callback from something not written in Objective C, you should create your own autorelease pool anyway (in the callback).

Answer (score 3):

`NSThread` is a wrapper on top of pthread, so `pthread_self` will always return a valid thread object if the thread was created using the `NSThread`, pthread, GCD or the C++ threading API!

`[NSThread currentThread]` will also return a `NSThread` object even if the thread wasn't created using the `NSThread` API and using public API it's impossible to tell wether the returned object is just a proxy or an "actual" `NSThread`.

You can use the `@autoreleasepool` directive to spawn a lightweight autorelease pool.

Comment: But what if I try to get the threadDictionary from that [NSThread currentThread] returned for such a pthread? would I crash? get a "nil"? I must be able to differentiate threads that HAVE an autorelease pool, from those who don't. Creating a @autoreleasepool {} around every log-line seems to be too much for realtime audio threads that call me once every 20 milliseconds or so. Or Am i wrong here?

Comment: @MottiShneor You get an empty dictionary back. The returned thread object doesn't just act as a proxy, but is a completely normal `NSThread` object. Also note, just because you know it is a `NSThread`, doesn't mean that it automatically has an autorelease pool attached to it! `NSThread` doesn't implicitly create an autorelease pool on your behalf, so you shouldn't make the assumption that your thread has one.

Comment: @MottiShneor You can wrap your whole function body in an `@autoreleasepool`. Also, 20milliseconds is A LOT of time, you can create and drain a lot of empty or nearly empty pools in that time without any problem. In general, don't try to guess if your code is slow and make preemptive optimizations. Write your code, profile it and then tackle the real performance killers if it is too slow!

Comment: Thanks a lot - real info here :). In reality, I know for sure each NSThread has its autorelease pool. Our iOS/MacOS app creates and manages them. My problems stem from a 3rd-party library I am forced to use, which is undocumented and creates lots of internal threads. It is written cross-platform in C++. I DONT KNOW the nature of the calling threads, and their tightness, so I want to prepare for the worst. Being iOS, I don't want to temper with performance. I think I'll follow your suggestion, and wrap Obj-C logger calls in @autoreleasepool scopes.

Comment: @MottiShneor If you create the NSThread objects, you can give them a name and check the name property of the thread. But it's probably simpler and faster to just wrap everything with `@autoreleasepool`, having a pool lying around and not doing anything won't harm your performance, and creating/draining one are really minor operations (taking only a fraction of a millisecond, even on older iOS devices)